# delete query is not working when both columns are selected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, operators, sql-delete

```
create table demo11 (dn int, rn varchar(max))
insert into demo11 values(1,'A'),(1,'A-1'),(1,'A-3'),(2,'A'),(2,'B'),(2,'C'),(3,'A-3'),(3,'A-4')
```

| dn | rn |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A-1 |
| 1 | A-3 |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | A-3 |
| 3 | A-4 |

Expected result:

| dn | rn |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A-3 |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | A-4 |

Tried with following query but not worked:

```
delete from demo11 
where DN NOT in (1,2,3) AND RN NOT IN ('A-3','C','A-4')
```

Comment: Your `DN NOT in (1,2,3)` effectively excludes your **entire** data set.

Comment: whats the goal of the query? preserving the maximum of column RN per DN?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. "Got this"/"want that" with no explanation of how the two are related does not help us help you. Nor does "but not worked" explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to delete, just select by using a *window function* such as `ROW_NUMBER()`

```sql
SELECT dn, rn
  FROM
  (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dn ORDER BY rn DESC) AS rnum,
          d.* 
     FROM demo11 AS d 
  ) AS dd
 WHERE rnum = 1
```

If you insist on deleting those values, then use the *window function* again such as

```sql
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT dn AS dn2, rn AS rn2
   FROM
   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dn ORDER BY rn DESC) AS rnum,
           d.* 
      FROM demo11 AS d 
   ) AS dd
  WHERE rnum > 1 
)
DELETE 
  FROM demo11
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE rn=rn2 AND dn=dn2)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd089fb6decb2c0a92bac373242803dc)</kbd>

Comment: It is working correctly, but when I placed this code in my project application it is working for some cases and not working for other  cases. Could you write the query with delete query without CTE so that will be useful for ex: use delete from table where condition

Comment: @rahul I can't know your test case but rewrite as [you desired](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0062e8e10d30a0ffe3119d135a43ceba)

Answer (score 0):

First, define which records you would like to preserve,
e.g. for the maximal RN per DN

```
SELECT dn, max(rn) rn_max from demo11 group by dn
```

Then, exclude these records from the deletion:

```
DELETE FROM demo11 d   
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT dn, max(rn) rn_max from demo11 group by dn ) tmp
    ON d.dn = tmp.dn AND d.rn = tmp.rn_max
    WHERE tmp.dn is null
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tried with following query but not worked:
>
> ```
>    delete from demo11 
>    where DN NOT in (1,2,3) AND RN NOT IN ('A-3','C','A-4')
> ```

It doesn't work like that, even just in basic terms of sets of data. Here's a simpler example:

```
John, Chicago
John, New York
Jane, Chicago
```

I want all rows that aren't John from Chicago. This means I want John/NewYork and Jane/Chicago.

If I say `name <> 'John' and city <> 'Chicago'` I exclude everything. Jane would have been kept because her name isn't John, but her city is Chicago, which isn't "not Chicago". This is the same as saying `name NOT IN ('John') and city NOT IN ('Chicago')` - the core problem here is that you're trying to exclude "John from Chicago" as a pair of values, but these two clauses (1: `name <> 'John'`, 2:`city <> 'Chicago'`) *do not work together* - the *do not keep the values together*. Some rows are excluded because they are `John`, other rows are excluded because they are `Chicago` - there isn't any notion of a pair of values `John+Chicago` with this

What was actually wanted was `NOT(name = 'John' AND city = 'Chicago')`. In this, the data remains paired up. John/Chicago stay together as a clause and the NOT operates on the pair of them. This is very different to some rows being excluded because of one thing and other rows being excluded for another thing

Some databases allow multiple values in a NOT IN, so they would also permit a construct like:

```
(name, city) NOT IN ('John, 'Chicago')
```

The pairing of John/Chicago are again kept together and work in unison to exclude just one row where the values are John/Chicago as a pair

---

Other answers have given you the SQL you need to use, but I wanted to talk about *why your try didn't work*. You need to appreciate that on their own, your two truth statements `DN NOT in (1,2,3)` and `NOT IN ('A-3','C','A-4')` work separately and affect different rows. There isn't anything at all that keeps the values inside the two INs paired up together.. If your database had:

```
(DN, RN) NOT IN ( (1,'A-3'), (2,'C'), (3,'A-4') )
```

Then it would have worked out, because those DN/RN pairs are kept together. If you don't have a database that works like that, then you have to use something more like:

```
NOT (
  (DN=1 AND RN='A-3') OR (DN=2 AND RN='C') OR (DN=3 AND RN='A-4')
)
```

These also keep the data pairs you're looking for "together" in that it's `this and that` or `this2 and that2` or `this3 and that3` (not)